# How can I recover XMR sent to my Reddit account with Tippero?

Tags: wallet-recovery, tipping, tippero

Reddit it currently down. On #Monero IRC they said that it was possible to contact operator of tippero to claim XMR tips even if Reddit was down. How would I go about doing that?

I am not in hurry and will be patience. I trust that Reddit is not an exit scam and will rise from the dead to live again. But please teach me this lesson so I can improve my XMR and Tippero expertise.

If my IRC and Reddit accounts are not linked, how can I recover my Reddit XMR tippero balance if Reddit not work?

Answer (score 4):

I think the only way would be to contact fluffypony or moneromooo on IRC and somehow prove that you were the owner of the reddit account holding the coins. I'm not sure how exactly you could do that if reddit was down at the time, but maybe they would be able to think of something. If they accepted that you were the reddit account owner, then shifting the coins to your IRC account would just be a matter of modifying a couple of database entries.